# hierarchical indexing not working in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been unsuccessful in reproducing the hierarchical indexing example on page 148 of Wes McKinney's "Python for Data Analysis" book. I am currently using python 2.7 on Mac OS X 10.8.2. (I have the same problem on ubuntu precise as well with pandas 0.7-0.10).

Any and all help is appreciated.

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3)), index = list('aabb'), 
                  columns = [['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Colorado']['Green', 'Red', 'Green']])
```

Error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-681f4740a561> in <module>()
      1 frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3)), index = list('aabb'), 
----> 2                   columns = [['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Colorado']['Green', 'Red', 'Green']])  

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

FYI I am using version 0.9 of the pandas library:

```
pd.__version__
'0.9.0rc1'
```

Comment: thanks @hayden for editing my question /formatting the code..

Comment: FYI, pandas official 0.10.0 is out since end of December.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the book, but it looks like you left out a comma:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((4, 3)), index = list('aabb'), columns = [['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Colorado'], ['Green', 'Red', 'Green']])
```

Note the comma between `'Colorado']` and `['Green'`.